# High voltage comparator

Tags: voltage, dc, high-voltage, comparator

We are trying to make an high voltage window comparator circuit

**The following are the design constraints**
I cannot resistor divide the voltage as it would load the input
Unable to find a high voltage buffer

**Input**
Can be from 0.5 to 400 vdc
We do not have any problem till 70v as there are buffers available

To continue the above context, if we are able to detect this window then we will be able to switch the inputs to different signal conditioning circuit

Please suggest

This is basically a voltage measurement circuit

Comment: Start with a voltage divider?

Comment: Any voltage measurement will load the source to some extent. Please [edit] your question to add details of the source impedance and what load you *can* tolerate. You also need to specify your accuracy requirement.

Comment: *I cannot resistor divide the voltage as it would load the input* - I doubt that  - you need to justify what that is so.

Comment: Input buffer THEN voltage divider? (Needs 400V supply)

Comment: Hi @transistor since it's a measurement unit and the voltage to be measured is unknown at this point but a range is specifed of 0.5v to 400v. Basically trying to make a DC voltmeter

Comment: Suitable sized resistor values can make voltage divider that minimizes loading effect. For example 1M ohm and 10Mohm voltage divider can create 36V from 400V with only 36uA current draw.

Comment: @siddharthtaunk, note that you did not answer either of my questions and just repeated what you had written in your question. Please take time to read the comments carefully and **[edit]** your question to add in the missing details.

Comment: Yes @brian that's the reason we wanted a comparator to compare voltage levels and switch to different signal conditioning circuits which will reduce the voltage.

Comment: So just use a very high resistance divider. Then buffer it so the high impedance divider doesn't muck with your input. Everything will be a load anyways. It's just a matter of how much. You may also use a current-limiting series resistor and a diode clamp depending on the details of how you need this comparator to work. Again, use a really big resistor.

Comment: You are still not answering any questions, just restating what you already said. VTC as unclear.

Answer (score 5):

I have had similar requirements for HV systems used in Photo-multipliers where the typical load is nano amps, so the supply is very small. It is not accurate to say you can not load it, because any system, resistors, comparators etc will produce a load.

Below are two options based on your needs:

1. **[~10M-100M Ohm Load] -** Use a very large resistive divider to not load your source, or since you know the exact resistive load, account for the losses in your control system etc. Then buffer the output with a JFET style op-amp or an emitter follower (Both would have typically > \$10^{12}\$ Ohm input impedance). I would use something like 10M and 1M resistors for dividers, and potentially a capacitor on the lower half to reduce noise.
2. **[~ >\$10^{12}\$ Ohm Load] -** Provide a 2nd rough high voltage supply to use for buffering (Does not have to be regulated, just higher then what your signal is). Then use a high voltage FET and create an "Emitter Follower" (Or in FET terms, Source Follower). This would provide a lower impedance copy of your signal, that could then be divided with resistors in the 100's of kilo range in the event you need a stronger signal with lower noise.

Also, just an FYI, Even high end measurement systems like 1000 USD DMMs and 10,000 USD scopes often have input impedance in the 1M ohm range. Not that you can not get a special system with higher, but if your comparing what your making to something commercially available, they do not have insane front ends due to load vs noise tradeoffs.

Also Note: the above solutions could have issues if you really are trying to measure down to 0.5V. Buffers, Emitter followers etc. might need a supply that goes below your measurement ground for this to work... I would say 10V minimum you should be safe with a 10:1 divider and a common gound.